# ADF mobile with WSDL not working

Tags: android, wsdl, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Hi I am developing an ADF mobile application using WSDL link as a data source. When I deploy it to the android emulator and run the application it throws the following error

> HTTP status code 500 Internal Server error: The server encountered an
>   unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> Unable to get value for the property due to invalid binding iterator.

Can anyone tell me why this error is coming?

Answer (score 0):

Could be many reasons - one thing to check is the ip-address you used for your WSDL and whether it is accessible from the android emulator. Try opening it in the browser on the emulator.

Comment: Hi Shay.. thanks for the reply... the WSDL link opens in my desktop browser but not in my emulator.. could this be a reason?

Answer (score 0):

the invalid iterator was coming due to the return values being empty when the app loads and it expects data to be available. So use the `<amx:setpropertylistner/>` and for the 500 error it can be many reasons. for me it was because the emulator could not access the internet as i needed to connect to a proxy. So giving the proxy credentials worked. Then there were other WSDL that also gave the 500 error. Used SOAPUI (guess everyone should use this to see the errors) and found Integration Broker of PeopleSoft from where i used the WSDL was giving an error. Found it was because the request handler was inactive so the request was not processes and a fault message was being sent to me due to which the error occurred. Changed it to active and it worked.